# List all subjects having a given property in Sparql, from Wikidata

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am trying to get all the triples `<subject, predicate, object>` which contain the `P31` property as predicate from Wikidata using their SPARQL interface. I think the query should be something like this.

```
  SELECT ?s ?p ?o WHERE {
   {
       ?s ?p ?o.
       FILTER (?p=P31)
       
   }
}
```

where, `P31`, is the property I want.

Answer (score 4):

Using SPARQL, your query could look like this

```
SELECT ?subject ?object WHERE {
  ?subject wdt:P31 ?object
}
```

but it will most certainly hit a timeout given that either P31 or P279 are expected to be set on each of the (currently) 35 millions entities. You can try it with a limit though: via the [GUI](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fsubject%20%3Fobject%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fsubject%20wdt%3AP31%20%3Fobject%0A%7D%0ALIMIT%201000%0A%0A) or [as JSON](https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?format=json&query=SELECT%20%3Fsubject%20%3Fobject%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fsubject%20wdt%3AP31%20%3Fobject%0A%7D%0ALIMIT%201000%0A%0A).

If you really need to get a list of all the triples with a P31 property, the only possible way I'm aware of is to use the [Wikidata dumps](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Database_download), and eventually use `grep` or [`wikidata-filter`](https://github.com/maxlath/wikidata-filter) to get a subset of it.

Comment: Please can you mention, how I can use the other 2 possible methods you mentioned, for getting data in form of <Subject,predicate,object> for all predicates having P31

Comment: Most public SPARQL endpoints do have a default limit for obvious reasons. Thus, it's more about understanding that a single request won't return the whole resultset. To handle this, one has to use `LIMIT n OFFSET (n*i)` which is also known as pagination.

Comment: @darth he means to download the dump and process it via some local SPARQL API, triple store or whatever

Comment: I meant predicate property P31. As in, all triples of form: <some subject> <instance of (which is P31)> <some object>

Comment: Also, Is there any way of getting the Whole List of these Triples ?

Comment: @darth, there exists partial dump with all membership statements, however it is more than one year old: http://tools.wmflabs.org/wikidata-exports/rdf/exports/20160801/dump_download.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
SELECT ?s ?p ?o WHERE {
  {
    ?s ?p ?o.
    FILTER(?p = wdt:P31)
  }
}
LIMIT 20
```

Refer to this [link](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_query_service/User_Manual#Basics_-_Understanding_SPO_.28Subject.2C_Predicate.2C_Object.29_also_known_as_a_Semantic_Triple)